# Transforming Java object to JSON via XSLT

Tags: java, xml, json, xslt, jaxb

I already have

- a working JAXB setup for Schema A
- a working JAXB setup for Schema B
- an XSLT transformation from instances of A to instances of B (and vice versa)

If I have an XML instance of type A, I can use XSLT and Jettsion to produce a reasonable JSON representation of B. But what I really want to do is take a Java object of type A, a JAXB marshaller, my existing A->B XSLT, and a Jettsion XMLStreamWriter to produce JSON of type B, without having to produce an instance of B (XML or Java) in between.

```
Java Object A --> JAXB Marshaller --> ? --> XSLT A to B transfrom --> JSON B
```

I have an idea that I should be able to this by marshalling to a SAXResult that in turn act as an XMLReader that can feed the XSLT translation. I need a kind of ContentHandlerAdapter that can coordinate the marshalling with the transformation.

But here my head starts spinning.

Has anybody seen or written a setup like this, and hopefully point me to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the object and an instance of `Marshaller` (or `JAXBContext`) in `JAXBSource` and pass that to the `Transformer`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Answer (score 0):

That is the purpose of the trax `TransformerHandler` interface.

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
// or just use new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl() for Saxon (XSLT 2.0)

Source xslt = new StreamSource(....);
TransformerHandler handler =
    ((SAXTransformerFactory)tf).newTransformerHandler(xslt);
Result result = new StAXResult(theJettisonStreamWriter);
handler.setResult(result);

SAXResult marshallerResult = new SAXResult(handler);
// marshal to the marshallerResult as normal
```